# Why have hreflang versions of pages been deindexed?

Tags: seo, google-index, hreflang

We have different versions of our site and link these via Hreflang tags.

For some reason Google has deindexed these pages (apart from the French version of the site).

These screen shots showing the deindexing.

[image]

[image]

We only have a few errors showing in search console and these seem to be for old 404 pages:

Our sites url is: twistedtime.com

Answer (score 1):

Dont always go with the numbers there as everything is not always accurate for one of many reasons.

Looking up your French areas, it appears everything is working fine. Put this in Google search, and this is a good way to see what pages are in fact showing up in the search. Again, this is for your French link, remove the FR to get all pages.

You can do that for the /us and /au versions as well. I see 9 and 10 pages for each.

```
site:twistedtime.com/fr
```

Comment: Hi. Yes FR isn't an issue for some reason it is only AU and US that have been deindexed.  There should be 300+ pages indexed for each.  If you check the above images you can see these were indexed at one point but have now been removed.